# iOS mobile safari treatment of telephone links

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, zurb-foundation, html5boilerplate

So I've seen telephone links being treated in 2 different ways on mobile safari on web pages. (on ipad and ipod touch):

1 - On my one page, when I click on the link it just displays a popup saying: "Cannot Open Page. Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"
HTML code looks like: `<a href="tel:15551234455">1-555-123-4455</a>`  (just an example of what my real number looks like)
Also here I'm using plain HMTL mobile boilerplate as codebase

2 - On another page, when I click on the link, it displays a popup giving the user 2 options, Add to Contacts and Copy.
HTML code looks like: `<a data-height-watch="" class="button button-block no-border trackConversion" href="tel:15551234455" style="height: 40px;">Call 1-555-123-4455</a>` (another example of the real code)
Runs on Foundation Zurb

Is this something one can control progammatically? If so, how can I make sure the user is met with the 2nd "response"? Does it maybe have to do with Foundation Zurb?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this depends on device specifications. Also if you have any third party plugins installed in your device such as skype, then it may work differenty.